# Glitch in Main Page Design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

the link to the picture does not close properly.
there is a '<' missing in the closing  tag.

And also the system here is stupid, I get following error message:

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

It does not meet our quality standards.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your complaint about an image refers to. As far as I can tell everything seems to render and function properly. As for your comment about our system being stupid, if your running into the quality standards message your post must be excessively basic. If its that simple, it really should be a comment rather than an answer, and if it was a question, it was sure to have FAR too little information to be adequately answered without someone asking for more information.

Comment: The title on the picture had malformed HTML that made it read "Dawn at the Pool/a>".  Can't speak for the other stuff.